# Google maps, update directions on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to show 3 different routes to the same point on google maps (or any maps as an alternative), on my website, so I have map shown on the top, and three clickable boxes under it, and when a user click on specific box the map would show direction according to it. Example image attached, from viamichelin site. To be more clear, I have same end point for all 3 cases, but different start points.
What would be the best approach here, I couldn't find anything regards this in gmaps documentation? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: so what have you tried? can you provide minimal code that recreate the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using first of all some examples on Google Maps API documentation and in particular their [Direction Service.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) Within the Direction Service, you want to look for the Direction Request object and the Direction Response object. These are basically the main objects for getters and setters in your application. Here you have a simple [jsbin application.](https://jsbin.com/jexizew/2/edit?js,output)

```
for (var j = 0; j < response.routes.length; j++){

            var dirDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                dirDisplay.setMap(map);
                dirDisplay.setDirections(response); 
                dirDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("setPanel"));
                dirDisplay.setRouteIndex(j);
                dirDisplay.setOptions({
                    draggable: true,
                    hideRouteIndex: true,
                    polylineOptions : {
                        strokeColor: colours[j],
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 5
                    }
                });

        }
```

In case you are not familiar with this, the above code is where the magic happens, that is where you get the response from the query and show the available routes that returned from the servers. Of course, you can customize the map and the routes as you wish, this is just an example.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, and I'm testing it. However, I don't need alternative roads between two points, I need 3 different end points, and same start point, and when I click on specific link/box/whatever the map should update the road. For example end point in all 3 cases should be Paris, and I need roards from Barcelona, Vienna and Prague to it.

Comment: Okay, have some progress here: https://jsbin.com/magixefela/edit?js,output  Trying to add directions here as well, so when someone chose something from a drop-down list directions will show on the right.

Comment: It is starting to look good and taking shape. Check the link I have sent you on the Direction Service. The DirectionsRenderer class has a setPanel() method that will populate the results in your map. Compare and contrast the examples there with mine so you will get additional inspirations for your app. If you think is fair to accept my answer, please do so, if that has been useful.

Comment: Thank you once again! This is what I end up with:https://jsbin.com/woyiyurago/edit?js,output  It seems that alternative routes in the top right box isnot updating correctly though, nor map is changing when I choose specific alternative. I'm not familiar with javascript, and I'm sure there's some bug. May you take a look at it please? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Quick note to say this is a question/answer platform, not else. Having said that, I am happy to look into it once you accept my answer. Just click the green thingy you have on your screen...well deserved I think, will you agree?

Comment: I'm newbie around here, so not really into the procedure, sorry about that.Your answer is more than helpful, and you are more than helpful so far! Thank you.

Comment: Still can't figure what's the problem with updating the right column when I click on route alternatives, looks like it's buggy right now, and I have no clue where to look at.

Comment: I have looked into it but you need to post a new question while making sure that you explain what you have done and the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: I just posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501875/google-maps-alternative-routes-wont-update  Thank you!