# Google maps alternative routes won't update

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a directions map from one point to multiple specific point. When one change end point the map should update, and alternative routes should be shown on the right sidebar, with details under it. However, when I change end point it's not updating nicely, sometimes it just add alternative directions under "old" directions,sometimes alternatives are messed up, not really sure what the problem is, though I suspect that there might be a problem if theres's no alternative routes returned for the specific end point. Here's a preview of what I made so far:

```
jsbin.com/hoqebofice/edit?output
```

Also in the end, I'd like to have map updated once alternative route is clicked from the right sidebar as well.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site (like jsbin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnChangeHandler add this line:

```
 var onChangeHandler = function() {
      document.getElementById("setPanel").innerHTML = ""; // THIS ONE!
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
```

Comment: That's actually really helpful, and it's way better now, working without bugs. The last thing is if it's possible to update map when one of the alternative routes from the right is selected?

Comment: Is not easy as I thought I think is not posible directly, I suggest opening another question with the sample code both in StackOverflow as the External jsbin (with no api_key) , so more people can help figure this out

Comment: Thank you, I just posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515826/update-map-on-alternative-route-select