# Update map on alternative route select

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to update google map shown on the left when alternative route from the top-right is clicked ("suggested routes"). Currently it only list alternative routes and directions under, but won't update map itself when the route is clicked. I'd like map on the left to be updated once something from the suggested routes is clicked, so it shows specific route instead.
HTML:

```
<div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Do: </b>
    <select id="start">
      <option value="Bosis, Valjevo">Bosis, Valjevo</option>
    </select>
    <b>Od: </b>
    <select id="end">
      <option disabled selected value> -- Izaberite -- </option>
      <option value="Belgrade, Serbia">Belgrade, Serbia</option>
      <option value="Novi Sad, Serbia">Novi Sad, Serbia</option>
      <option value="Užice, Serbia">Užice, Serbia</option>
      <option value="Čačak, Serbia">Čačak, Serbia</option>
      <option value="Loznica, Serbia">Loznica, Serbia</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="setPanel"></div>
   <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

JS:

```
 function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: {lat: 44.291971, lng: 19.9722431}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
          document.getElementById("setPanel").innerHTML = ""; // THIS ONE!
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          provideRouteAlternatives: true,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            // set loop to iterate through from the response.routes array

            console.log(response.routes.length);
            console.log(response.routes);

            for (var j = 0; j < response.routes.length; j++){

                var dirDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                    dirDisplay.setMap(map);
                    dirDisplay.setDirections(response); 
                    dirDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("setPanel"));
                    dirDisplay.setRouteIndex(j);
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    dirDisplay.setOptions({
                        draggable: true,
                        hideRouteIndex: true,
                        polylineOptions : {
                            strokeColor: colours[j],
                            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                            strokeWeight: 5
                        }
                    });

            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

Here's working preview:

https://jsbin.com/hamotuduxi/edit?output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing map to setMap() and it is out of scope. 
Try to move the var map to the global scope, just above your function initMap;

```
var colours = ['#1FD2CF', '#FF4000', '#FFFF00'];
var map;
function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: {lat: 44.291971, lng: 19.9722431}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var onChangeHandler = function() {
            document.getElementById("setPanel").innerHTML = "";
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}
```

Also, where do you get the colours from in your calculateAndDisplayRoute function?

Just add an array of colours as shown in the example and it should work...

Comment: Thank you, however it seems that when I use that code the sidebar on the right with the directions is not updated, to be more pricise it just adds extra alternative directions when I click on one from the top-right bar, but the previous directions stays on top. Also the display on the map from the left window is a bit confusing, it shows all alternatives at once, but should display just the one that is selected at that moment.

Comment: your original question: "'I' d like to update google map shown on the left when alternative route from the top-right is clicked ("suggested routes"). Currently it only list alternative routes and directions under, but won't update map itself when the route is clicked. I'd like map on the left to be updated once something from the suggested routes is clicked". The snippet I have provided just do that.

Comment: As a reminder, this is an answer / question platform and not a place where you can build your applications for free. The code above solve the specific issue which was asked for in the original question. So you are now talking about a different sets of issues in "your code" that you should at least try to solve on your own by putting a little effort into it. Accept my answer please and post another relevant question for your specific problem. Alternatively you can hire me....:)